# How do we know the form of a partial fraction expansion?

Tags: partial-fractions

If you take a quick gander at the table on this page:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx

You'll notice there are some rules about what the form of a partial fraction expansion should be, based on the factors of the original rational function.

At this point I have learned partial fractions at school more than 3 times, but no one bothers to explain the reasoning behind these rules. Now I'm frustrated because every time I do it myself, I can never remember how to do it right and end up looking up the table on the linked page above.

So my question is, how do you "derive" these rules for the form of a partial fraction expansion?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Sketch_of_the_proof)

Comment: While this is the direct answer to my question, I'm having a great deal of trouble understanding this proof (what is unicity of a Taylor Polynomial? Why is it that $P - Q_iA_i = O((x-\lambda_i)^{v_i})$ implies divisibility? Exactly what is Taylor's Theorem?). Furthermore, the point of asking the question is precisely because I'm sure other people are confused by this as well, and also have difficulty understanding the reasoning on Wikipedia.